# jQuery code causing memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

The following code is causing a memory leak (you can see this happening the more you hover in and out the slower it gets). Unfortunately I am unable to download a javascript profiler in my office (I can, it will just take me a few days/ weeks).

Here is the code, just some simple transitions for a dropdown menu:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    breadcrumbOver = function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#3393b5", textIndent: 15 }, 250);
    }
    breadcrumbOut = function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#738793", textIndent: 0 }, 250);
    }
    $("nav ul li").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).children('ul.child').stop().slideDown('fast').children('li').hover(breadcrumbOver, breadcrumbOut);
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).children('ul.child').stop().slideUp('fast').unbind(breadcrumbOver, breadcrumbOut);
      }
    );
});
```

Can anyone see where a memory leak may be occuring?

Edit: Live example here - http://rcnhca.org.uk/sandbox/ (Repeatedly roll over "Health, Safety and Security" then roll over it's children to see the effect happen, also the animation slideDown doesn't fire sometimes if you roll in and out fast enough).

Comment: Most times, The way we code causes the memory leak.

Comment: What have you seen occurring in your browser developer tools? If you watch, your various animations are probably revealing themselves to you. You can possibly tell a lot from this.

Comment: @veeTrain I only have firebug, it is show nothing unusual except it throws this error: "WebGL: Can't get a usable WebGL context." which is to do with Modernizr not my script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem looks like it might be in your initial selector. It targets all `li` tags under a `ul` under `nav`, which includes all children and grandchildren.

```
$("nav ul li") ...
```

This causes it to add a `hover` callback to all `li` tags under `nav`, then when you hover it adds yet another `hover` callback.

You might want to be more specific with it, such as specifically targeting the direct children.

```
$("nav>ul>li")
```

If you have children classes, you can also use `:not(.child)` to target everything that's not a child. Use `console.log` (which is built into Chrome or using Firebug) to log what those selectors are pulling to make sure you're getting what you expect.

Comment: Thanks I followed this advice but it is still happening. I put a live example up at http://rcnhca.org.uk/sandbox/ if your interested.

Comment: I'm honestly not seeing any problems with the example.

Comment: after hovering in and out of the dropdown's parent many many times the animations on it's children become sluggish and choppy.

Comment: Not for me. Win7 Chrome, Fx and IE9 work fine and the animations are very smooth, despite how many times I try to trick it.

Answer (score 2):

I see what you're talking about George; the effect is most noticeable when swiping between elements rapidly after the box has been opened several times.

Perhaps this will be something that impacts what you're seeing. I read up on `stop()` and felt like it could have an impact on what you're seeing. The first attribute you could specify in `stop()` is clearQueue. The second is equally interesting. Here is what the documentation says about it:

> **clearQueue** A boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.
>   **jumpToEnd** A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.

Might be worth a shot to pass in true like this:

```
$(this).children('ul.child').stop(true, true)...
// (or  you want the animation to unwind, I suppose)
$(this).children('ul.child').stop(true)...
```

Also, I checked out [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) as well and I don't think you can pass in two events like you are. Perhaps you could use it this way and not experience the problems you are:

```
...unbind(breadcrumbOver).unbind(breadcrumbOut);
```

Comment: Thanks +1, you're right about the `unbind()` however the problem still exists even if I use just `unbind()` which should remove all bound listeners. I also tried with all the different stop paramaters and it still slows down =/

Comment: Bummer...well, I hope you can rely on users not mousing over that many times before they navigate somewhere :-) Great point about calling `unbind()` with no arguments. But aren't you binding to `children('li')` and then unbinding `children('ul.child')`?